# inheritance-diagrams in sphinx for matlab

Tags: matlab, inheritance, python-sphinx, diagram

I am documenting a matlab code that I have with sphinx. I am using the package [sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain).

My directory tree is as follows:

```
me:~/.../doc$ tree ../
../
├── doc
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── BaseClass.rst
│   └── DerivedClass.rst
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── BaseClass.m
    └── DerivedClass.m
```

The problem comes when I want to show inheritance diagrams. I have added the necessary things in my config.py file:

```
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath('..')

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram',
    'sphinx.ext.graphviz',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinxcontrib.matlab',
]
primary_domain = 'mat'
```

And I have the following in the index.rst file

```
Welcome to BGK's documentation!
===============================

I am trying to have a diagram here...

.. inheritance-diagram:: BaseClass DerivedClass
   :parts:2

.. graphviz::

   digraph {
      "From here" -> "To" -> "Somewhere";
      "From here" -> "To" -> "Somewhere else";
   }
```

And in the output the directive `inheritance-diagram` is ignored, obtaining directly the next diagram that I am using to test that I can plot diagrams.

[image]

Is there any incompatibility to plot inheritance diagrams with sphinx for matlab classes? Is there any way to go around the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You might need to include the module to make your inheritance graph work: `.. inheritance-diagram:: yourModule.BaseClass yourModule.DerivedClass`

Comment: Hello @dfri . the only thing that I can consider as a module is the folder containing the file. If i add it as `.. inheritance-diagram:: src.BaseClass src.DerivedClass`, it is stil not working. I have also tried to add or remove the extension .m in all the possible combinations. It is still not working.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram` extension is for the Python domain only. It does not work for Matlab.

Comment: Hello @mzjn, do you have any source to confirm this? In such a case I you can post this in the answers and I can tag the answer as correct. Not the answer that I was expecting :( , but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx does not support this. The built-in `sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram` extension is for the Python domain only. It does not work for Matlab. If it did, I'm sure it would say so in the Sphinx documentation (and a glance at the source code in sphinx/ext/inheritance_diagram.py confirms that it is only for Python).

The only way inheritance diagrams for Matlab could work is if some other extension provided the functionality. The `sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain` extension that you use does not.

Comment: Might be unrelated but worth pointing out that this still holds true as of 2022 but if anyone's looking for a way to make dependency diagrams (inheritence involved). [m2html](https://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/) uses graphviz's dot to automatically create dependency diagrams from supplied matlab files.